# Why site open in Quirks mode in IE all version ?

Tags: internet-explorer, layout, quirks-mode

When i open my site in IE (all Version 7,8,9) its open in Quirks mode and i didn't find any solution to resolve this .

So please help me

Comment: Do you have an example the html/css/js on your site? It could be many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body onLoad="blinkFont()">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
<head>
```

My money is on that beauty... Followed by the `script` tag outside of the closing `html` and `body` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your site does not start with an blank line before the doctype declaration. But it could be a number of other things as well.

Maybe [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) can also help you (there is a list of doctype errors which can trigger quirks mode).

**edit**

In your specific case: the doctype should be the first line. Not `<body onLoad="blinkFont()">`.

You may benefit from validating your site here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgsateams.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0